# Codeigniter session user_data is empty

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-2

I am trying to store below data in Codeigniter session(database)

```
$session_data = array(
    "name"=>$user_details['name'],
    "email"=>$user_details['email'],
    "role"=>$user_details['role'],
    "status"=>$user_details['status'],
    "mobile"=>$user_details['mobile'],
    "permissions"=>json_decode($user_details['permissions'],TRUE),
    "country_id" => $country_details['country_id'],
    "country_name" => $country_details['name'],
    // "countries" => $active_countries
);
$this->session->set_userdata("user",$session_data);
```

This is absolutely fine and the data is stored in the database like below under `user_data` column in `ci_sessions` table.

```
a:2:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:4:"user";a:8:{s:4:"name";s:9:" Test";s:5:"email";s:18:"email@email.com";s:4:"role";s:11:"super_admin";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:6:"mobile";s:10:"1234567890";s:11:"permissions";a:9:{s:9:"dashboard";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"all";}s:8:"settings";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"all";}s:9:"employees";a:5:{i:0;s:4:"list";i:1;s:3:"add";i:2;s:4:"edit";i:3;s:6:"delete";i:4;s:4:"view";}s:7:"drivers";a:5:{i:0;s:4:"list";i:1;s:3:"add";i:2;s:4:"edit";i:3;s:6:"delete";i:4;s:4:"view";}s:5:"rides";a:5:{i:0;s:4:"list";i:1;s:3:"add";i:2;s:4:"edit";i:3;s:6:"delete";i:4;s:4:"view";}s:5:"users";a:5:{i:0;s:4:"list";i:1;s:3:"add";i:2;s:4:"edit";i:3;s:6:"delete";i:4;s:4:"view";}s:4:"cars";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"list";}s:3:"ads";a:5:{i:0;s:4:"list";i:1;s:3:"add";i:2;s:4:"edit";i:3;s:6:"delete";i:4;s:4:"view";}s:7:"country";a:5:{i:0;s:4:"list";i:1;s:3:"add";i:2;s:4:"edit";i:3;s:6:"delete";i:4;s:4:"view";}}s:10:"country_id";s:3:"174";s:12:"country_name";s:5:"QATAR";}}
```

But, when I un-comment the countries array index from the `$session_data` array, record is created in the database but the `user_data` column value is empty. But when I am printing in the same controller, it displays all data

```
$session_data = array(
    "name"=>$user_details['name'],
    "email"=>$user_details['email'],
    "role"=>$user_details['role'],
    "status"=>$user_details['status'],
    "mobile"=>$user_details['mobile'],       
    "permissions"=>json_decode($user_details['permissions'],TRUE),
    "country_id" => $country_details['country_id'],
    "country_name" => $country_details['name'],
    "countries" => $active_countries
);
$this->session->set_userdata("user",$session_data);
print_r($this->session->userdata['user']);

Array ( [name] => Ways Test [email] => test@email.com [role] => super_admin [status] => 1 [mobile] => 1234567890 [permissions] => Array ( [dashboard] => Array ( [0] => all ) [settings] => Array ( [0] => all ) [employees] => Array ( [0] => list [1] => add [2] => edit [3] => delete [4] => view ) [drivers] => Array ( [0] => list [1] => add [2] => edit [3] => delete [4] => view ) [rides] => Array ( [0] => list [1] => add [2] => edit [3] => delete [4] => view ) [users] => Array ( [0] => list [1] => add [2] => edit [3] => delete [4] => view ) [cars] => Array ( [0] => list ) [ads] => Array ( [0] => list [1] => add [2] => edit [3] => delete [4] => view ) [country] => Array ( [0] => list [1] => add [2] => edit [3] => delete [4] => view ) ) [country_id] => 174 [country_name] => QATAR [countries] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [country_id] => 99 [iso_name] => IN [name] => INDIA [image] => uploads/country_image/IN.png [nicename] => India [iso3] => IND [numcode] => 356 [phonecode] => +91 [currency_code] => Indian rupee [currency_name] => INR [currency_symbol] => ₹ [distance_unit] => kilometer [status] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [country_id] => 174 [iso_name] => QA [name] => QATAR [image] => uploads/country_image/QA.png [nicename] => Qatar [iso3] => QAT [numcode] => 634 [phonecode] => +974 [currency_code] => Qatari riyal [currency_name] => QR [currency_symbol] => ر.ق [distance_unit] => kilometer [status] => 1 ) ) )
```

Assuming this could be a memory size issue, I changed mysql data type for `user_data` from Text to LargeText. Still not working.

Is there any issue with Cookie? My assumption is, cookie is just holding the reference of the session database not the actual data. Since, i feel cookie size is not a problem

Config:

```
$config["sess_cookie_name"] = "ci_sessions";
$config["sess_expiration"] = 7200;
$config["sess_expire_on_close"] = FALSE;
$config["sess_encrypt_cookie"] = FALSE;
$config["sess_use_database"] = TRUE;
$config["sess_table_name"] = "ci_sessions";
$config["sess_match_ip"] = FALSE;
$config["sess_match_useragent"] = FALSE;
$config["sess_time_to_update"] = 300;

$config["cookie_prefix"] = "";
$config["cookie_domain"] = "";
$config["cookie_path"] = "/";
$config["cookie_secure"] = FALSE;
```

Database Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_agent` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_data` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Authentication.php (Controller)

```
if($result['success']===true && $result['user_details']['status']=='1'){
    $user_details = $result['user_details'];
    $model_call = $this->country_model->active_countries();
    $active_countries = $model_call['active_countries'];
    // Getting country details
    $model_call = $this->country_model->get_country_details($user_details['country']);
    $country_details = $model_call['country_details'];

    $session_data = array(
        "name"=>$user_details['name'],
        "email"=>$user_details['email'],
        "role"=>$user_details['role'],
        "status"=>$user_details['status'],
        "mobile"=>$user_details['mobile'],
        "permissions"=>json_decode($user_details['permissions'],TRUE),
        "country_id" => $country_details['country_id'],
        "country_name" => $country_details['name'],
        "countries" => $active_countries
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata("user",$session_data);
    redirect("myadmin/dashboard");
}
```

Dashboard.php (Controller)

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
    //var_dump($this->session->userdata['user']);
    exit();
    if(!isset($this->session->userdata['user'])){
        redirect("myadmin/authentication"); 
    }
}
```

I am using codeigniter version 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Posting your table structure would be really helpful, nevertheless, one possible cause of this is the country index itself. I am assuming you're using $this->db->insert to save this session to your database. The country index is is an array thus creating a server error. I suggest you debug the model you are using to insert these datas.

putting the below code after your insert should show errors.

$this->db->_error_message();
$this->db->_error_number();

Comment: I am not using any `$this->db->insert` since Codeigniter session class will do that. However, I tries printing `$this->_error_message()` after `$this->session->set_userdata('user',$session_data)`. There is no error message

Comment: Please share your table structure and class

Comment: I have added in the question

Comment: can you try print_r($_SESSION) after $this->session->set_userdata('user',$session_data) and post them here

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the new version of codeigniter, I had a similar problem and that solve it!